# Convert string to integer that may or may not start with zero

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm trying to convert a String to a number with parseInt, the problem is that it doesn't keep zero at the beginning.
For example, if I have:

```
0011222
```

Converting:

```
parseInt('0011222') //prints 112222 and not 0011222
```

Is there a way to do this conversion, taking into account that you may or may not have these zeros?

Comment: Which number starts with 0? Other than 0 ofcourse :)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Well, every number which is bigger than zero and less than one^^ That is just uncountably more than infinitely many :*

Comment: It isn't advisable to define every number you are talking about as integer just because that comes from the OP. I'm also not going to discuss this any further - this is the wrong platform for that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the zeros then you have to keep it as a string. Why do you want a number whit zeros since 0011222 == 11222 as numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's parsInt will strip leading zeros from a number before type conversion.
Integer can not have padded zeros.

I am assuming that you are trying to convert the integer to use in some operation but still keep a reference to the original string value as well.

You can use an object structure like this where the key is original string and value is the o/p from parseInt integer.

let strNum = {'0011222': 11222, '00001': 1 };